# SQL Server 2005 Management Studio Language Settings

Tags: sql-server-2005

I'm working with a Korean language copy of SQL Server 2005.  I'm not familiar with the software so I have to match buttons by hotkey, comparing with screenshots from tutorials when my limited Korean fails me.

Is there a way to switch the whole thing's language to English?  Would I have to download a language pack, and if so, where are they available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know it's not possible to change the interface language of SSMS. There is also no language pack downloads available.

SQL Server Management Studio can be downloaded from here:
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=22985

Please keep in mind that date and currency format will still be fetched from Control Panel -> Region and Language settings.

HTH